# how to edit mouse selected string and put back into the whole string

Tags: javascript, jquery

so far I have the following codes.

```
<div id="allText">
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>text4</li>
  <li>text5</li>
</div>

<button type="button" id="editButton">Edit</button>

<script>
    $(function(){

      $("#editButton").click(function () {

        var txt = '';
        if (window.getSelection) {
            txt = window.getSelection();
        } else if (window.document.getSelection) {
            txt =window.document.getSelection();
        } else if (window.document.selection) {
            txt = window.document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        var n = txt.toString();
        n = n.replace("</li><li>","<br>"); 
    //document.getElementById("allText").innerHTML=n; 
        console.log(n);
      });

    });

</script>
```

I want to use my mouse to select some texts in the middle and when I click the edit button, the selected text will be update, and the other unselected text will stay the same.
I can get the selected text and replace to work, but not sure how I can put that replace string back in the middle of the whole string.

for example:
Like if i selected

```
    </li>
<li>text3</li>
<li>
```

I want my final string to be

```
<li>text1</li>
<li>text2<br>text3<br>
text4</li>
<li>text5</li>
```

any idea?

Comment: Selection.toString() doesn't return the html of the selection, it returns the text only. So in your example selection the value of n would be something like "\ntext3\n". It looks like you may want to utilize the node properties of the Selection object instead to manipulate the DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: Maybe contenteditable help http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp